# VBA for entering formulas

Tags: excel, vba, formulas

I have a worksheet keeping track of the number of clients from specific cities in a specific state and am using the =SUMPRODUCT formula to count the clients from each area.  there are over 200 different cities represented in this report, and I have been entering each formula manually as it has to be adjusted to include the correct city and state value for each cell.  Is there a macro that can automate this?

In Column A, I have the names of every city from the master list (Column U contains all of the cities and column V contains all states) and in Column B, I am entering the formula.  For example, the formula is A7 is: =SUMPRODUCT((U2:U666="ALEXANDRIA")*(V2:V666="VA")).  The formula has to be be changed for each row in column B to include the correct city.  Is this a process that can be automated using VBA? Or will I need to continue manually entering the formulas?

Comment: almost anything can be automated in excel with the help of VBA but SO is not a code-writing service...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your sheet structure so that Column A is City, Column B is State, then your formula in Column C would be:

`=SUMPRODUCT(($U$2:$U$666=A1)*($V$2:$V$666=B1))`

Then you can copy the formula down.

Your other option is to use built in features like Pivot Tables and not recreate the wheel.